# Weblogic - JMS Server is not displaying any destination

Tags: jms, weblogic, weblogic12c, devops

I've a JMS configuration for Weblogic which include: A Server (which is running fine), a JMS Server (addressed by my Server) and a JMS Module. The JMS Server is not displaying an "OK" health state but no exception was found on logs and my JMS module (which contains some queues) is not displaying any JMS destination, also, no errors on logs. Any idea/clue?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0 has a bug (Bug 22481818) affecting JMS module. So, in order to fix it you need to apply a patch: 21830665.